# I am trying to capture data from my input fields on the lowest level component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props, reactstrap

I have my **state** located in my APP level component, and I am trying to capture the data being put into my form component. I am using hooks, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong!

I have tried putting the state on the form level, but it returns undefined, my end goal is to send this data to firebase, and have it displayed in a table on another page of my App.

**APP**

```
import React, { useState, createRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import About from "./components/About";

const App = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [hours, setHours] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**HEADER/ROUTER component

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import Data from "./pages/data/Data";
import About from "./pages/about/About";
import Contact from "./pages/contact/Contact";


import "../style.css";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar">
          <NavLink className="link nav-item" to="/entry">
            Time Entry
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="link nav-item" to="/data">
            Data
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="link nav-item-right" to="/about">
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="link nav-item-right" to="/contact">
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/entry" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/data" component={Data} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**HOME Page component**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import InputForm from "./Form";

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <InputForm />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**FORM component**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, createRef } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from "reactstrap";

const InputForm = props => {


  const dateEntry = createRef();
  const nameEntry = createRef();
  const hourEntry = createRef();
  const descriptionEntry = createRef();

  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDate(dateEntry.current.value);
    setName(nameEntry.current.value);
    setHours(hourEntry.current.value);
    setDescription(descriptionEntry.current.value);
    // console.log(nameEntry.current.value);
  };

  return (
    <Form className="data-entry">
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Date</Label>
        <Input type="date" className="input" ref={dateEntry} />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Lease Acconting Manager Name</Label>{" "}
        <Input type="text" className="input" ref={nameEntry} />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Hours Worked</Label>{" "}
        <Input className="input" ref={hourEntry}/>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Description</Label>{" "}
        <Input type="textarea" className="input" ref={descriptionEntry}/>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default InputForm;
```

Comment: You're not importing `Home` anywhere according to that code. Is that right? I would have expected it in `App`.

Comment: If you want to reuse your handlers of the form a good patter that will save you from a los of propdrilling will be to use a reducer or something similar.
Other approach will be to pass your handlers to the InputForm.

Comment: I just uploaded my header/router component to show where everything is being imported from, I am trying to learn React Router...

Answer (score 1):

Firts you should question why are you setting the state of the **APP** with values that are going to be used just by the **InputForm**. If you are just going yo use them in the **InputForm** you should move your state to that Component.

Maybe just set the `state` inside the **InputForm** instead iof use the `createRef` so you can handle them there without *propdrilling* or something.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, createRef } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from "reactstrap";

const InputForm = props => {

  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [hours, setHours] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  /* Im not sure How this works inside your component Input, but why dont just use a onChange?*/
  const dateEntry = createRef();
  const nameEntry = createRef();
  const hourEntry = createRef();
  const descriptionEntry = createRef();

  const handleInput = ( e, type)  => {
    switch( type ){
     case'name':
       setName( e.target.value );
     break;
     case'date':
       setDate( e.target.value );
     break;
    case'description':
       setDescription( e.target.value );
     break;
     case'hours':
       setHours( e.target.value );
     break;
    }
  }

  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Just submit your data or something...  
  };

  return (
    <Form className="data-entry">
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Date</Label>
        <Input type="date" className="input" ref={dateEntry} onChange={ e => {handleChange( e, 'date') } } />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Lease Acconting Manager Name</Label>{" "}
        <Input type="text" className="input" ref={nameEntry} onChange={ e => {handleChange( e, 'name' ) } } />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Hours Worked</Label>{" "}
        <Input className="input" ref={hourEntry} onChange={ e => {handleChange( e, 'hours') } }/>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Description</Label>{" "}
        <Input type="textarea" className="input" ref={descriptionEntry} onChange={ e => {handleChange( e, 'description') } }/>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default InputForm;
```

If you need to access the `Form` values from any other component try to implement the same with a **context**, and maybe try to add them some **actions** and **reducers**.

Chek this if you need more info : 
[Context Docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), 
[Reducer Docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Answer (score 1):

You can best go with `react redux` but in the case where you don't want to, You should create an app level function  and propergate it through all the children till the `InputForm` component where you will use the onchage callback in the `Input` to pass the event through back to the parent. depending on the implementation of the function at the parent componeent `App` you will set the value to state, propergation should be something like

```
const App = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [hours, setHours] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
 handleChange = (e) => {
  //logic to set the specific value to state
  // you can use e.target.value as well as e.target.name to capture the value and decice which state variable to update. eg.
  if(e.target.name =="name") setName(e.target.value)
//do same for all the other state variables
 }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header handleChange={handleChange } />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Then inside of Header component you have it as follows

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar">
          <NavLink className="link nav-item" to="/entry">
            Time Entry
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="link nav-item" to="/data">
            Data
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="link nav-item-right" to="/about">
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink className="link nav-item-right" to="/contact">
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/entry" render={(props) => <Home {...props} />}  />
          <Route exact path="/data" component={Data} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Then the home component will be as follows

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

import InputForm from "./Form";

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <InputForm handleChange={props.handleChange} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

At the form level now you can do the following

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, createRef } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from "reactstrap";

const InputForm = props => {
//using the handleChange function propergated from the parent component we will send the event and use it at the parent to collect the name and value artribute of the input. 

  return (
    <Form className="data-entry">
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Date</Label>
        <Input type="date" className="input" onChange={(e)=>props.handleChange(e)}/>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Lease Acconting Manager Name</Label>{" "}
        <Input name="name"  onChange={(e)=>props.handleChange(e)} type="text" className="input"  />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Hours Worked</Label>{" "}
        <Input name="hours" className="input" onChange={(e)=>props.handleChange(e)}/>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="form-entry-items">
        <Label className="label">Description</Label>{" "}
        <Input type="textarea" name="description" className="input" onChange={(e)=>props.handleChange(e)}/>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button >Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default InputForm;
```

Comment: This still throws an error that the `props.handleChange` is not a function

Comment: @rstowe1 Which of the component throws the error is it the `InputForm`?

Comment: yeah, the error is being thown on change from the `InputForm`

Comment: You should backtrack and see where the handleChange lost being a function that is if you didn't miss the name. trace back in each of the component and do `console.log(typeof props.handleChange);`

Comment: It is received as a function everywhere except in the App component where it is undefined

Comment: you should check the names which you pass as props to the component which is not seeing it as a function.

Comment: `typeOf` show as everything as a function, but when the `onChange` occures i get an error message saying `handleChange` is not a function...